# python - how can I dynamically create a function with a name based on a string read in from a file?

Tags: python, dynamic-function

Let's say I have a file containing the string "unpredictable_words".  I would like to read in this string and then define a function as follows:

```
def test_unpredictable_words(self):
    do_important_stuff()
```

I would then like to inject this function into a class definition so that this function can be called on any instances of this class.

How can I accomplish this?

I looked a bit at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/8160676/1701170 - but I don't think it does what I want, exactly, or at least I can't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
>>> def injected(self):
...     print 'injected'
... 
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> A.injected = injected
>>> a = A()
>>> a.injected()
injected
>>> def func2(self):
...     print 'func2'
... 
>>> setattr(A, 'injected2', func2)
>>> a.injected2()
func2
>>>
```

Comment: I don't follow.  Your answer does not have a function name that is dynamically determined based on a string.  Injecting the function isn't the hard part for me.  Knowing how to define a function with a named based on a string is the part I don't understand.

Comment: I think the answer has all the necessary bits to accomplish what you need. You have a class `A` in which you want to inject a new method. Extract method name from a file, define any function (name doesn't matter) with the needed code, use `setattr(A, method_name, your_defined_function)` to inject a new method.

Comment: Functions in Python are first class citizens. Function name doesn't really matter and you can assign the same function to several variables. So your "Knowing how to define a function with a named based on a string" doesn't make sense for me. Define any function, then inject it under a different name into your class.

Comment: thanks.  Your example seems to be working.  I agree with you that function names should not usually matter, but I'm using Python unittest - it runs every function with a name that starts with "test" as a separate unit test, so it seems that the function name is important for using unittest.

Comment: Ok, so do something like `setattr(TestCase, 'test_' + test_function_name, defined_function)`

Comment: I was needing something like this, also for `unittest`. If you also need a dynamic function that changes action based on some variable input, take a look at closures.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to define a function under one true name. Functions are first-class entitiens, you can pass them around and assign to variables. On top level, you use `globals()`, withing another function, `locals()` to bind a name:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...   return x + 1
... 
>>> name = 'unpredictable_words'
>>> 
>>> globals()['test_' + name] = foo
>>> 
>>> test_unpredictable_words(1)
2
>>> 
>>> def some_function():
...   locals()['test_' + name] = foo
...   return test_unpredictable_words(1)
... 
>>> some_function()
2
>>>
```

Sometimes you still want that the function knows its name, in order to appear nicely in a stacktrace. Now `test_unpredictable_words` appear as `foo` in error messages. This is not easy to fix, since that name is stored in `foo.func_code.co_name` and can't be changed.